# Nodejs URL modifications for SEO purposes

Tags: node.js, url, routes, seo, url-rewriting

I have a working App built on Nodejs + Drywall + Openshift, sorry it's in Arabic. Basically, I am looking to improve on the service, but having a major roadblock. The site is a classifieds site and I need to optimize it for SEO, however, my links to ads are shown like this...

http://yobyobi.com/ads/show/55c9ff9dcf68970612ba2d38

55c9ff9dcf68970612ba2d38 is the Ad ID on my mongoDB, I do also have a record for the indicating the date and the title of Add combined "Sun-Nov-22-2015-8-pm-2007-camry-for-sale", the goal is to make the URL pretty and understandable by search engines. The end result I want to accomplish is one of the following:

1. yobyobi.com/ads/show/55c9ff9dcf68970612ba2d38/Sun-Nov-22-2015-8-pm-2007-camry-for-sale
2. yobyobi.com/ads/show/Sun-Nov-22-2015-8-pm-2007-camry-for-sale/55c9ff9dcf68970612ba2d38
3. yobyobi.com/ads/show/Sun-Nov-22-2015-8-pm-2007-camry-for-sale/

Now, option number 3 would be ideal, but would slow down my application if I have to search by Ad title instead of Ad ID. Similar to what Stackoverflow is doing (attached pic)

### [Stackoverflow example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHVeq.png)

### Code

app.get('/ads/show/:id', require('./views/account/ads/index').read);

The above line returns the Ad for me with all the details including the title that I want to use, but the problem is that I cannot change the route URL after I receive the title.

I am not sure if this module would help in whatever I am trying to do it's called "named-routes"

Has anyone ran across this problem? If so can you share some insight on how to best tackle the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

well, the solution was dead simple, do the following:

add * as a wild card like this

app.get('/ads/show/:id/*', require('./views/account/ads/index').read);

now when you create the links to the post, attach anything where the * is and it should show the same Ad without breaking the page.

Cheers